# installing Rodeo on CentOS with VirtualEnv (no SUDO permissions)

Tags: python, virtualenv, rodeo

I'm trying to install Rodeo on a remote machine with CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 and without SUDO permissions, therefore I'd like use it in my VirtualEnv setup.
I was not able to find the solution on the official page, can you help me?

Comment: your remote machine has x server installed?

Comment: A quick google search led to [this site](http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/01/running-rodeo-within-a-virtualenv.html) that provides an explanation.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "x server". Concerning the site you mentioned, there's the suggestion "Now that we’re in our new virtualenv called “Rodeo”, we can install the required packages." without any explanation.